# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager

Tags: java, sftp, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to fetch files through SFTP. I could able to fetch the files from SFTP Server to Windows using Java program but the same Java program is not working in UNIX it is giving the error mentioned in the subject line. The jar is available in the program. Below is the code i am using for the same. Can some one help on this please.

```
package com.tgt.ftp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.*;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.*;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.*;

public class GetMyFiles {
  static Properties props;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetMyFiles getMyFiles = new GetMyFiles();
    if (args.length < 1)
    {
        System.err.println("Usage: java " + getMyFiles.getClass().getName()+
                " Properties_filename File_To_Download ");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String propertiesFilename = args[0].trim();
    String fileToDownload = args[1].trim();
    getMyFiles.startFTP(propertiesFilename, fileToDownload);
  }

  public boolean startFTP(String propertiesFilename, String fileToDownload){
    props = new Properties();
    System.out.println("Vamshi============>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFilename));
        String serverAddress = props.getProperty("serverAddress").trim();
        String userId = props.getProperty("userId").trim();
        String password = props.getProperty("password").trim();
        String remoteDirectory = props.getProperty("remoteDirectory").trim();
        String localDirectory = props.getProperty("localDirectory").trim();

        //Initializes the file manager
        manager.init();

        //Setup our SFTP configuration
        FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, true);
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);

        //Create the SFTP URI using the host name,userid,password,remote path and file name
        String sftpUri = "sftp://" + userId + ":" + password + "@" + serverAddress + "/" + 
                remoteDirectory + fileToDownload;

        // Create local file object
        String filepath = localDirectory + fileToDownload;
        File file = new File(filepath);
        FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        // Create remote file object
        FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(sftpUri, opts);
        // Copy local file to sftp server
        localFile.copyFrom(remoteFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
        System.out.println("File download successful");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        manager.close();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show you classpath configuration for windows and linux. It's very likely that the linux set-up is missing a jar file.

Comment: @BetaRide, Class path in Windoes: <classpathentry kind="lib" path="commons-vfs2-2.0.jar"/>  and in Unix export CLASSPATH="commons-vfs2-2.0.jar".